# Custom Excel Formats that reference cells

Tags: excel, formats

I would like to have an Excel sheet that displays a custom format. The custom format uses the contents of another cell. Here is an example:

```
Column A : Show a column of numbers in accounting format in the currency of cell(b1).

Cell(B1) : "XYZ"
```

The intention is that users can enter their own currency. I know there are formatting tools to do this in Excel but this is a question that implements a custom format based upon another cell contents. That's the real question...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer is "no", although of course the functionality can be implemented with VBA

Comment: Yep - I thought so. Right now it's a custom function but it feels a little inelegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want something like this:

[image]

[image]

..then just put this in the Sheet Module:

```
Sub worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sFormat As String

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("NumberFormat")) Is Nothing Then
    sFormat = Chr(34) & Target.Value & Chr(34) & " "
    Range("FormatWhat").NumberFormat = sFormat & "$#,##0;" & sFormat & "[Red]-$#,##0;-"
End If

End Sub
```

...and give B1 the Name NumberFormat in the Name Box:

[image]

...and likewise name some or all of column A "FormatWhat".

(Using Named Ranges avoids hard-coding references in your code. If you hard code cell address into your code, those references will be pointing at the wrong place if you (or a user) later adds new rows/columns above/to the left of those hard-coded references. Using Names avoids this, and makes for more robust code.

I *almost never* hard-code cell addresses in my code. I *almost always* use Excel Tables aka ListObjects to hold any data that VBA interacts with for the same reason...ListObjects are dynamic named ranges that Excel automatically expands/contracts to suit the data.)

Comment: Thx. Yes named ranges best and this a clear answer. Quick Q - is there Workbook_Change too in case this is a global thing...

Answer (score 3):

A worksheet_change in the worksheet's private code sheet can alter the number formatting in column A.

```
private sub worksheet_change (byval target as range)
    if not intersect(target, range("b1")) is nothing then
        if len(cells(1, "b").value2) = 3 then
            dim f as string
            f = ucase(cells(1, "b").value2)
            f = "0 \" & left(f, 1) & "\" & mid(f, 2, 1) & "\" & right(f, 1)
            range(cells(2, "a"), cells(rows.count, "a").end(xlup)).numberformat = f
        end if
    end if
end sub
```

There are a maximum number of custom number formats that can be added to the existing number formats without deleting previously created cnfs; I think it's around 30 or so.

Comment: Good answer - although I marked the other answer as "correct" because code a little clear and the examples made it fuller. I did up vote yours though. Thx